# Corda Example Application - Springboost server not showing APIs

Tags: corda

I've set up the example app and I have 3 nodes running (tutorial says I should have 4; notary,A,B,and C) lacking node C is not my issues though. I run ./gradlew runPartyAServer and it starts the SpringBoost Server and I get a CordaApp template page a localhost:50005 but there are no APIs or the example landing page.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

- checked out `github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/Basic/cordapp-example/`
- built and ran nodes `./gradlew clean deployNodes && ./build/nodes/runnodes`
- started the server `./gradlew runPartyAServer`
- connect to `localhost:50005` and I see this
  [image]

Check out the logs in `/client/logs` to see if anything strange happened, maybe something like this (which could be caused by something wrong going on with the connection to the node):

> Caused by: net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to
> server(s). Tried with all available servers.  at
> net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:282)
> ~[corda-rpc-4.6.jar:?];